# Django Handler Not Sending Emails to Admins

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send error messages through the admin handler, my settings.py is as follows:

```
LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'handlers': {
            'celery' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            },
        },

        'loggers': {
            'celery.webapp.task' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['celery'],
                'propogate' : False,
            },
        },
}

ADMINS = (('whoami', 'blab@something.com'))
SERVER_EMAIL = 'blab@something.com'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp1.something.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'blab@something.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is where it is calling:

```
#Logging the counters (Mail)
logger = logging.getLogger('celery.webapp.task')
logger.info("Continue Mapt:" + str(counter_start_mapt))
logger.info("Continue Datt:" + str(counter_start_datt))
logger.info("Continue Sett:" + str(counter_start_sett))
logger.info("Continue Rebuild:" + str(counter_start_sett_rebuild))
```

When using mail send, I could send emails, however, with the admin mail handler, it doesn't use email_host, but instead server_email. Is there a way to set ports, host for server email?

Comment: do you notice the syntax error ? You are missing a leading `'` before the email, and a trailing `'` after `EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Comment: oooops, I tried to make some edits covering up my real email, and accidently removed ==> '

Comment: ok. in the shell, can you try to send an email with your smtp server settings correctly ? Also, `ADMINS` needs to be a tuple of tuples or a list of tuples.

Comment: The list of tuples work... I forgot the ==> ',' comma

Comment: @karthikr Here I am almost 7 years later, your comment just saved me hours of headscratching.  If you're still active, please make that comment an answer so that I may upvote it.  If not, I think I shall post it as a community wiki.